# Use ganache accounts in web3j

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, web3-java

When trying to use https://github.com/web3j/sample-project-gradle I encounter this code:

```
    // We then need to load our Ethereum wallet file
    // FIXME: Generate a new wallet file using the web3j command line tools https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html
    Credentials credentials =
            WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                    "<password>",
                    "/path/to/<walletfile>");
    log.info("Credentials loaded");
```

I wanted to use network created by ganache-cli. I did successfully connect to the network but I can't find the wallet files. Is there a way to use here accounts generated by ganache-cli?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ganache-cli is a personal blockchain. It does not create wallet file, rather provides private key to load credentials.

```
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("0x78c0cf2c035dda3c46953fb7b926f8ece0aa8bfed6c012e33d5e289e6e0c1ebc");
```

Comment: Yep after learning a little bit more I have understood the differences. Thanks for help!